# Copy Template From Webpage And Paste In Gmail Signature

Tags: html, templates, copy, gmail, signature

I created an Html template. I can copy from browser by selecting the complete template and on pasting it in the gmail signature editor all the formatting and image urls are copied from the template correctly. Now I need to keep a button on which if I click the same template must get selected and copied. But I am not able to understand what is the type of the selected template. Is it rtf? How do I achieve this in JavaScript. I already tried selecting using $('#id').html() and pasting the content using document.execCommand('copy');

This is the function I created to which I pass `$('#id').html()` -

```
const copyToClipboard = str => {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
};
```

But when I paste it in gmail signature box only the html code gets pasted.

Need to understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Web application that take HTML as input from users use something called HTML sanitizer. The web security risk with having user supplied HTML in a page is: if the page fails to properly strip all scripts, a malicious user will be able to run arbitrary javascript and hijack the user experience (i.e. the page will be vulnerable to XSS).
What sanitizers do is, examines a HTML template and produce a new HTML template preserving only the tags that are designated to be 'safe' and desired.

Comment: So how do I achieve the above mentioned behaviour. I need a button to copy a template and must be able to paste it in the email signature box.

Comment: I can't help you with the exact solution but you'll have to do all the stuff that you are doing in entirely HTML. Gmail is quite aggressive about it's security policies. So, they won't allow you to do wired stuffs with JavaScript. Also, kindly accept the answer if it is helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Sorry cannot mark it as answer.